# Android SurfaceView consumes memory after closing

Tags: android, memory, surfaceview

Android surfaceView still consumes memory after finishing the activity and killing the thread. Memory usage increases every time I restart my game (closing and opening). Cant figure it out :(
Surface Destroyed method:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){

                holder.lockCanvas();
                thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
                thread=null;


        }

    }
```

Surface created:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        if(thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        thread.start();

}
```

This method finishes the activity:

```
private  void restart()
    {
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(false);
        thread=null;
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: Any piece of code is really helpful to analyze :)

Comment: I added some methods. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Changed some code, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting lauchMode to singleTask. Thanks to this: [Memory and Activities :: OutOfMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022679/memory-and-activities-outofmemory)